# ASM print function using bios calls

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bios, osdev

I am trying to add a print function to a ASM kernel that I am writing, though I have tried many with no success. Most, like the one from [osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Babystep2), simply print out: ?, or two happy faces. I am using the mikeos bootloader and qemu.  This is my current kernel, which print out gibberish infinitely:

```
%include "print.asm"

os_main:
    hello db "Hi!", 0
    mov si, hello
    call print
    jmp $
```

Contents of print.asm (from a tutorial):

```
print:
    pusha

; keep this in mind:
; while (string[i] != 0) { print string[i]; i++ }

; the comparison for string end (null byte)
start:
    mov al, [bx] ; 'bx' is the base address for the string
    cmp al, 0 
    je done

    ; the part where we print with the BIOS help
    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10 ; 'al' already contains the char

    ; increment pointer and do next loop
    add bx, 1
    jmp start

done:
    popa
    ret



print_nl:
    pusha
    
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0a ; newline char
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0d ; carriage return
    int 0x10
    
    popa
    ret
```

What is wrong with this code?  I am a new to assembly language, any help would be appreciated.

Assembler: nasm

Comment: Are you still in real mode while this code runs?  What output does it yield?   This is not a [mcve] and is insufficient to debug your problem.

Comment: Note that your `print` function reads the string from `bx` but you place a pointer to the string into `si`.  How do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are 2 errors in this code.

> ```
> os_main:
>  hello db "Hi!", 0
>  mov si, hello
>  call print
>  jmp $
> ```

You have placed the string at the label *hello* in the path of the program's execution! The CPU will execute those 4 bytes ("H", "i", "!", 0) as if they represented instructions. Obviously they aren't. Hence the output of gibberish.

This will work:

```
os_main:
 mov si, hello
 call print
 jmp $
 hello db "Hi!", 0
```

Like fuz wrote in a comment, the *print* code is wrong in that it uses the wrong address register (`BX`) to match your call (`SI`).

Better use next code:

```
; IN (si) OUT ()
print:
    pusha
    mov  bx, 0007h   ; BH is DisplayPage, BL is GraphicsColor
  start:
    mov  al, [si]    ; <<<<<<<<<
    cmp  al, 0 
    je   done
    mov  ah, 0x0E    ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  0x10
    inc  si          ; <<<<<<<<<
    jmp  start
  done:
    popa
    ret

; IN () OUT ()
print_nl:
    pusha
    mov  bh, 0       ; BH is DisplayPage (No need for GraphicsColor in BL)
    mov  ax, 0x0E0D  ; BIOS.Teletype CR
    int  0x10
    mov  ax, 0x0E0A  ; BIOS.Teletype LF
    int  0x10
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, though it ended up being a dumb reason that it did not work.  For reference, don't write the bootloader to the floppy first, write the kernel first... Doesn't make sense, but it works!